# Setting UP second setTimeout function won't execute JQUERY and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

```js
// Cart Code for Updating Database Quantity


$('.input-text').on('keydown ' , function(){

var tr_parent = $(this).closest("tr");

  setTimeout(function () {

    $(tr_parent).css('opacity', '0.3');
    
  
    }, 4000); 



 var input_value = $(this).val();
 var input_value_length = input_value.length;
 var product_id_update = $("#product_id").attr('data');


 if(input_value_length > 0 ) {


// Setting up time to execute jquery

  setTimeout(function () {

 $.ajax({
  url: "includes/ajax_code.php",
  data:{input_value:input_value, product_id_update : product_id_update},
  type: "POST",
  success:function(data) {

   $(tr_parent).css('opacity', '0.9');

   
  }

 });
    
  
    }, 5000); 




}




 });
```

Here the code is making the opacity of a input element to 0.3 just to give the user some indication that data is being transferred, my problem is than when I setup the second function setTimeout in the success area of AJAX it won't execute.

So the input stays with opacity or 0.3 all the time instead of going to 0.9  after AJAX finishes.

Comment: and what is data.error ??

Comment: It looks like a race condition... if the ajax call finishes inside of 3 seconds, then the opacity will set to .9, then set to .3, so it will end up at .3.  Try putting some console.log's in to see the order of the timeouts running.

Comment: Brian, thanks for the tip, you were right about the race condition. I fixed the issue by setting a time on the AJAX call to execute after 5 seconds .

Comment: So now the codes works, But if I write two numbers in the field or use delete in my keyboard, it will change opacity on every keystroke, so it looks like flickering, if type too many numbers. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the first opacity to 0.3 instantly, right before calling ajax, to indicate that something started to load. and set it back to 0.9 in success/error/done callback.

```
$('.input-text').on('keydown change', function() {


var table_row = $(this).closest("tr");


// $(table_row).css('opacity', '0.3');
var input_value = $(this).val();
var input_value_length = input_value.length;
var product_id_update = $("#product_id").attr('data');


if (input_value_length > 0) {
    $(table_row).css('opacity', '0.3');//<-- move here
    $.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    and in success callback, set it back to 0.9...either instantly or with a slight delay, doesnt matter.
```

Note: It looks like you are trying to submit data on every key press, which is probably a bit inefficient. I think you should "throttle" this ajax function. 
Set a timer when user edits an input for lets say 1 second. 
When time runs out, the input value is sent using ajax.
When user types another letter, the timer is reset, thus, the ajax is only triggered when user has finished typing for at least one second. Its simple optimization.

*Edit - created jsfiddle demo to show how it should be done *
 demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/49mjkagv/

```
<input type="text" class="input-text">
<img src="http://www.minefornine.com/pages/tpl/front/images/ajax_loader_big.gif" style="width: 24px; float: left;display: none;" id="loader" >


$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = $('.input-text');
    var timer;
    var loader = $("#loader");
    var loadStuff = function() {
      //input changed - set opacity to 0.4 to indicate loading
        input.css("opacity", 0.4);
        loader.show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            //loading finished 
            input.css("opacity", 1);
            loader.hide();
        }, 2000);//<--simulates ajax call  
    };
    input.on('keydown ' , function() {
        if ( timer ) {clearTimeout(timer);}
        timer = setTimeout(loadStuff, 1000);;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I resolved the issue by putting time on the AJAX call, So now the codes works, But if I write two numbers in the field or use delete in my keyboard, it will change opacity on every keystroke, so it looks like flickering, if type too many numbers. How can I avoid this?